# What is the usage of 'completed' in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Please specify the highest level of education completed qualifying you for university entry.

I don't understand the usage of 'completed' and 'qualifying'

I thought meanings like this
the highest level of education **was completed**.
you **have to qualify** you for university entry for specification of the education.

My interpretation is right? I don't understand the sentence structure. 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is correct.

If they are asking you  what you

> completed

They are asking the highest level of education you *attained*.

*Completed* has the added meaning that you received a certificate for completing this level, e.g. High School Diploma.

> qualifying

means it adds to your qualification for university since many universities have minimum requirement  levels which must be passed to be admitted.

Comment: btw, Do you know what the highest level of education means? If I have both High School Diploma and Bachelor degree, Bachelor is the highest level of education??

Comment: Bachelor Degree is higher, ranking from low to high is High School, Associate (usually for 2 year colleges), Bachelor, Masters, PhD. Are you applying for undergraduate or graduate program?